# How to retrieve the DOM object from the outer url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, iframe, npm

I need to create the database with the random text from different websites to do tests for my module that works on sentences. The more sentences I've got, the better, because the more cases I can predict and cover in algorithms. I've began doing this manually but it took me 8 hours to retrieve only 500 pages of text what is not very efficient.

I'm wondering if it could be possible to load the website into some npm module so I could get the DOM object of this website and then use JS to retrieve text from eg. `<p>, <h1-6>, <li>` elements. In the web browsers, in `F12` devTools window there's an access to the DOM. Would it be possible to get the access to the DOM with some desktop npm package likewise?

What I know is that there's no possibility to get the access to the DOM of outer website loaded into the iframe. What about using nodeJS from the desktop?

Comment: maybe something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom ?

Answer (score 1):

Well If I understood your question properly, i think this seems to be `web scraping` , and getting the DOM elements and things beneath under it , well if this is the case then you can use npm modules which does web scraping stuff, the one's which are quite well known npm modules are .

`1. Cheerio:`
It’s a server side version of jQuery , if your familiar with jQuery it would be hassle free to work on , moreover it’s lightweight and flexible to use . Basically after fetching the remote content (ajax request or any http request ), which can be  parsed same as  dom selection in jQuery , one drawback with this, it’s falls short in fetching dynamic content happened on the website or page .

---

`2. JSDom:`   This is closest thing to headless browser, which provides  close representation on the page or DOM , it uses websockets under its belt to return the content on the page and it also returns the dynamic content updated on the page

Comment: `web scrapping` - I didn't know that it's called so, thank you. Finally I figured out that I can also do it with phantomJS

Comment: @pawel yeah you can do the same with phantomJS .